# Como aplicar corretamente o String.Format

Tags: c#

Tenho o seguinte evento:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.tituloTela.InnerText = metodos.RetornarNomeMenuTitulo(((System.Web.UI.TemplateControl)(this.Page)).AppRelativeVirtualPath.Remove(0, 2));

    metodos.LiberarAcesso(this.Page, this.GetType(), Form_Cad);
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
      
        var objBonusVenda = new BonusVenda();
        if (objBonusVenda.ConsultarBonusVenda() > 0)
        {
             
            txtBonMaster.Text = objBonusVenda.BonMaster.ToString(String.Format("{0:0,0}", value1));
            txtBonFilhote.Text = objBonusVenda.BonFilhote.ToString(String.Format("{0:0,0}", value2));
        } 
       
    }

}
```

Que assim que carregar a página trazer os dados que existem na classe em forma de decimal, porém o campo está trazendo assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que o correto que eu preciso seria:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.

1 - Estou aplicando as máscaras nesses `Textbox` em `jQuery`

Código jQuery:

```
function aplicarMascaras() {
     $("#<%=txtBonMaster.ClientID%>").maskMoney({ showSymbol: false, decimal: ",", precision: 2, allowZero: false });
         if ($("#<%=txtBonMaster.ClientID%>").val() == "") { $("#<%=txtBonMaster.ClientID%>").val("0,00"); }

     $("#<%=txtBonFilhote.ClientID%>").maskMoney({ showSymbol: false, decimal: ",", precision: 2, allowZero: false });
     if ($("#<%=txtBonFilhote.ClientID%>").val() == "") { $("#<%=txtBonFilhote.ClientID%>").val("0,00"); }
 }
```

2 - Os campos declarados na classe e na tabela estão como decimal

3 - As váriavés `value1` e `value2`  estão declaradas no inicio do código.

Podem me ajudar a como formatar corretamente?

Comment: Como está configurada a cultura da aplicação/máquina? Tem certeza que quer configurar isso na plicação do servidor?

Comment: @bigown na verdade eu estou bem perdido nesse quesito, não sei onde posso tratar isso da melhor forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem entrar na questão de lado cliente/servidor,

o seu problema está sendo apenas o sinal `,` onde deveria estar `.`

Veja:

```
txtBonMaster.Text = objBonusVenda.BonMaster.ToString(String.Format("{0:0.0}", value1));
txtBonFilhote.Text = objBonusVenda.BonFilhote.ToString(String.Format("{0:0.0}", value2));
```

mas eu ainda faria dessa forma:

```
txtBonMaster.Text = objBonusVenda.BonMaster.ToString("0.00");
txtBonFilhote.Text = objBonusVenda.BonFilhote.ToString("0.00");
```